# Talend Open Studio (Eclipse based) stopped working after upgrade to 23.04

Tags: eclipse, dbus, qdbus

Since the latest upgrade (to 23.04), **Talend Open Studio**, the eclipse based OSS ETL stopped working.
When I launch it, it quits in the launch screen.

The error message reads as:

```
(Talend Studio:3481114): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 16:12:54.482: g_dbus_server_get_client_address: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_SERVER (server)' failed
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f6c41c3eb86, pid=3481114, tid=3481115
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (18.0.2+9) (build 18.0.2-ea+9-Ubuntu-2ubuntu1)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (18.0.2-ea+9-Ubuntu-2ubuntu1, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libswt-gtk-4944r26.so+0x3eb86]  Java_org_eclipse_swt_internal_C_strlen+0xf
```

I have found two similar errors in Google, [here in Garudalinux](https://forum.garudalinux.org/t/talend-eclipse-based-app-libswt-gtk-problem-since-last-pacman-system-update/27200) and [here in eclipse bug tracker](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=548806).
It seems the eclipse bug is related. At least, it relates to **dbus**, as my error message.

I am using a Kde Plasma desktop, under wayland. Talend Open Studio was running fine in 22.10 and before. The version of TOS I run is the TOS_DI-20211109_1610-V8.0.1 prebuilt binary from Talend.

Not sure how to troubleshoot that.
I can't find any core dump, maybe I have to set an option somewhere ?

EDIT: I opened an eclipse bug, and got this feedback:

> Webkit support is known to be very sensitive to the webkit version installed.
> How old is your Eclipse? WebKit$WebKitExtension doesn't exist on master, it is gone in 4.24.
> There were lot of changes in Webkit support in 4.24+, so no one will look at the older code now.

Then I explored the "upgrade eclipse" track in TOS code, but this is a huge project, and I'm far for competent in this area (Tycho, RDP, ...). Best answer I got on Reddit was that there is a reason why this is not upgraded, as it is so complex. Moreover it might not be Talend priority to do that work, as they focus on Saas and are about to be sold to Qlik...
So I think I'll run TOS in a VM for now, however inconvinient this is...

EDIT2: Found a workaround by using LXD
I made a LXD container under 22.04 with a GUI profile. This seems to work and isolate TOS from further upgrades... Seems viable for now.

Answer (score 0):

I am geeting the same error.  Tried to get an answer from Chagt GPT.  Here is what comes back.  I don't know how to proceed further, I'm using Fedora 38 which when this error was manifested after doing a version upgrade of the OS>

The error you provided seems to be related to a problem in the SWT (Standard Widget Toolkit) library for GTK (GIMP Toolkit) on a Linux system. Specifically, it indicates an issue with the strlen function in the C code of SWT.

To fix this issue, you could try the following steps:

```
Check for updates: Make sure that you have the latest version of SWT and GTK installed on your system. You can check for updates using your package manager or by visiting the websites of SWT and GTK.

Rebuild the library: If you have the source code of the library, you could try rebuilding it using a newer version of the SWT and GTK libraries.

Reinstall the library: If you don't have the source code or if rebuilding doesn't work, you could try reinstalling the library from a trusted source.

Contact the developer: If none of the above steps work, you could try contacting the developer of the library for support. They may have a solution or a patch for the issue.
```

It's worth noting that the exact solution may depend on the specific version of the library and the system configuration. Therefore, it's recommended to do some research and try different approaches until you find a solution that works for your particular case.

Comment: This error occured after upgrading Fedora 37 to Fedora 38 for me.  I spun upa fresh VM of Fedora 38 and installed Talend Open Studio and no issues.  Someting had to have been orphaned during the upgrade process.  I don't know where to go from here ad so if you have found a soltion that works would greatly appreciate hearing from you.

Comment: I received seperate  emai from another one of my posts on this issue.  Follow the  provided link It should fix the issue, link --> https://github.com/adoptium/adoptium-support/issues/785#issuecomment-1585740194.  the directory has be created every time your system is rebooted but creating the directory as mentioned fixes the issue.